# Remove spaces between characters in cell, but only if the space exists between two single characters

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, microsoft-excel-2013, find-and-replace

To process in 10,000 lines of excel, to remove spaces between characters in cell, but only if the space exists between two single characters.

`P J A JACKSON AND SONS`

should become

`PJA JACKSON AND SONS`

but

`JOHNSON AND SMITH`

should remain

`JOHNSON AND SMITH`

Comment: A VBA script would be the easiest way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using regular expressions and a find and replace.  On the Home tab, in the Editing group, click Replace to open the Find and Replace dialog box, If you don't see the Use wildcards check box, click More, and then select the check box.

Find:  `(<[^\s]>) (<[^\s]>)`
Replace:  `\1\2`

This will match all spaces between two single characters and then remove them. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using VBA.

To use:

Press `Alt` + `F11` - Copy the code into `ThisWorkbook`

You can run the code from: MS Excel - `View` tab - `Macros` (Hotkey: `Alt` + `F8`)
Or You can assign a button to it.

The Macro will apply on every used cell by default. If You need this modified, just leave a comment and I will update the answer with the requested modifications.

```
Sub remove_spaces()

Dim actives As String
Dim c As Range
Dim myStr As String
Dim myArray() As String
Dim wordsc As String
Dim wcount As Integer
Dim newStr As String

actives = ActiveSheet.Name


For Each c In Sheets(actives).UsedRange.Cells

    If c <> "" Then     
        wordsc = c
        wcount = WordCount(wordsc)

        ReDim myArray(wcount)

        myStr = c
        myArray = Split(myStr, " ")
        c = ""
        newStr = myArray(0)

        For i = 1 To wcount - 1
            MsgBox myArray(i)
            If Len(myArray(i - 1)) = 1 And Len(myArray(i)) = 1 Then

                newStr = newStr & myArray(i)

            Else

                newStr = newStr & " " & myArray(i)

            End If

        c = newStr

        Next i

    End If

Next c



End Sub

Function WordCount(fullText As String) As Long
Dim words() As String
Dim firstLetter As String
Dim i As Long

  words = Split(fullText)

  For i = LBound(words) To UBound(words)
    firstLetter = UCase$(Left$(words(i), 1))
    ' if it's alphabetic, +1 word
    If firstLetter Like "[A-Za-z]" Then
      WordCount = WordCount + 1
    End If
  Next i

End Function
```

Comment: Impressive Much love.

Comment: @JadeConnor - updated with working version. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells you wish to process and run this macro:

```
Sub formatter()
  Dim txt As String, i As Long
  Dim r As Range, txt2 As String

  For Each r In Selection
    txt = r.Text
    If InStr(1, txt, " ") > 0 Then
      ary = Split(txt, " ")
      txt2 = ary(0)
      For i = 1 To UBound(ary)
        If Len(ary(i - 1)) = 1 And Len(ary(i)) = 1 Then
          txt2 = txt2 & ary(i)
        Else
          txt2 = txt2 & " " & ary(i)
        End If
      Next i
      If txt2 <> txt Then
        r.Value = txt2
      End If
    End If
  Next r
End Sub
```